# How do I find the standard deviation that results in a specific probability coverage in a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Given a truncated normal distribution $X$ with mean $\mu$, lower limit $a$, and upper limit $b$. How can I pick a standard deviation $\sigma$ such that $P(\mu -x\leq X \leq \mu+x)=y$ for some arbitrary $x$ and $y$.

For a standard normal distribution $N$, 
$$P(\mu - \sigma \leq N \leq \mu + \sigma) \approx 0.68$$ 
More generally, 
$$P(\mu - z\sigma \leq N \leq \mu + z\sigma)= erf({z \over \sqrt 2})$$
By substituting $x = z\sigma$ we get,
$$P(\mu - x \leq N \leq \mu + x)= erf({x/\sigma \over \sqrt 2})$$ 
Then if we want the standard deviation that gives a probability of $y$ for the range $\mu - x$ to $\mu + x$ we can just solve for $\sigma$ in 
$$erf({x/\sigma \over \sqrt 2}) = y$$
How can we do the same for a truncated normal distribution.

Example:

Say I want a truncated normal distribution between 1 and 100 with mean 15. Additionally I want the area under the graph between 10 and 20 to be 0.7 (i.e. $cdf(20) - cdf(10) = 0.7$). How do I choose a standard deviation that fits the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For a truncated Normal distribution with truncation points $\underline a$ and $\overline b$, the cdf is $(\underline a\le x\le \overline b)$
$$F(X\le x)=\dfrac{\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{x-\mu\})-\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}{\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}$$
while the mean is
$$\mu+\sigma\dfrac{\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}{\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}$$
and the variance is
$$\sigma^2\left[
1+ \sigma^{-1} \dfrac{\{\overline b-\mu\}\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\{\underline a-\mu\}\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}{\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}-\left\{\dfrac{\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\varphi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}{\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\overline b-\mu\})-\Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{\underline a-\mu\})}\right\}^2
\right]$$

Comment: I'm not looking for the cdf of the truncated normal distribution. I'm looking for a way to choose the standard deviation of that truncated normal distribution to fit some criteria.

Comment: Well, this was the meaning of my post: from the cdf you can derive a confidence region or many, and from there a length that suits you for a particular variance or many.

Comment: +1 Connecting the question with this answer, it's pretty clear that all you need are these formulas and--exactly as stated in the question--you then use them to solve for $\sigma.$  There's no neat analytical solution; numerical procedures are usually needed.

Comment: If I want to pick a standard deviation $\sigma$ such that $P(\mu -x\leq X \leq \mu+x)=y$ for some arbitrary $x$ and $y$. I tried to solve for $\sigma$ in the following equation $F(X \leq \mu + x) - F(X \leq \mu - x) = y$. But I got stuck when I got to the erf. This is because I cannot integrate it to solve for $\sigma$.